# Rendering "~/bundles/jqueryval"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need your help, I have written this code to render the "~/bundles/jqueryval"

> The view Code

```
@model workflow.DataHolders.NewCompany

<link href="@Url.Content("~/sharedfiles/css/forms/addnew.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="Add_container">

    @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        <div id="validationMessage">Please Correct The Errors Below</div>
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateAndSignUp", "Accounts", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.ValidationMessage("CompanyName");
        <span class="field_title">Company Name: </span>
        @Html.TextBox("CompanyName")

        @Html.ValidationMessage("Email");
        <span class="field_title">Email: </span>
        @Html.TextBox("Email")



        @Html.ValidationMessage("Country");
        <span class="field_title">Country Name: </span>
        @Html.TextBox("Country")

        <span class="field_title">About The Company: </span>
        @Html.TextArea("Description")



        <input type="submit" value="Create New Account">


    }
</div>
<div class="get_connected_message">
    <h1>Get Connected with your Customers</h1>
</div>

<div class="get_connected_message">
    <h1>Build your profissional buisness world</h1>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

> Master Page Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MACE CRM</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/workflow/sharedfiles/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/workflow/sharedfiles/css/main.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>



<body>

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/shared/header.cshtml")

    <center id="body_container">
        <div id="content">
           @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </center>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/shared/footer.cshtml")
</body>
</html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/workflow/sharedfiles/css/smartDevicesVersion.css">
```

but unfortunately I get this error

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered
>   for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/MasterPage.cshtml": "Scripts".

so please could anyone help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the section within your "master page":

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```

Probably the best idea to include this in the `head` tag.

Otherwise it doesn't know what to do with your `Scripts` section defined in your child view.

The second parameter, which I've set to `false` is whether or not the section is required. If you set this to true and one of your child pages doesn't contain the section, you'll get a server error complaining that the section is missing.

Comment: what is second parameter?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I've added an explanation to my answer :)

Comment: @Mohammad No problems glad I could help :)

Comment: @mattytommo Why include it in the head tag? it will only slow down the page. Best to include it in the footer, one of the last elements to load. This will allow the HTML to be rendered first. You don't need the validation js untill you start typing. If you do not have html, there is nothing to type in..

Comment: @MihaiTibrea This is a common argument with JS -> head vs footer. I personally prefer it being in the head tag, see this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837921/is-it-bad-practice-to-embed-javascript-into-the-body-of-html

Comment: i understand that it is your personal preference, but you should explain to the user that accepted the anwer why you prefer a certain location if you make such a suggestion :)

Comment: this has a very good explanation on this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup so if you place them in the header, like @mattytommo suggested, make sure to add the correspoding **async** or **defer** tags